# How to manage versions and dependencies on a virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, amazon-web-services, deployment

I am new here on serverfault so bear with me please.

I am currently working with static web (`angular2`) and `php` deployment primarily on DigitalOcean and AWS using `nginx` and `apache2`.

Until now `debian` packages worked fine but in the near future I might need to deploy to CentOS and `debian` is out of the picture and I almost need to redo almost everything in a sense.

Also, for example the PHP version installed using debian is 5.5.* and if I need to upgrade I have to rely on third party repositories to get the job done.

Is there an easier and more universal way of managing software, versions and dependencies when deploying on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

Use a configuration management system to deploy your packages and server configurations.

Generally-speaking, most CM systems are able to handle differences between Linux distros fairly gracefully. However, what you'll run into is that package names between Debian and CentOS will differ. So you may need to manage two lists of packages - one for Debian and one for CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they're virtual machines doesn't make any difference, since what you're doing us at the OS level.

Depending on how you want to do it, Docker containers might be a good way to go, because it's portable between host OSs and it doesn't matter what you're running on.

Yes, you still need to manage the packages *inside* the container using some base image, but at least it's something you can tightly control.